# Pull from github without authentication every time

Tags: git, authentication, github, certificate

Is there a way to generate a certificate or such so that my prod server can pull from my github repo without me authenticating every single time?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is what [Deploy Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys) are for.

That help article explains what deployment authentication methods GitHub supports and gives some pointers to help decide between them.

In my limited experience, deployment SSH keys are probably the simplest to set up.

Answer (score 42):

You can [create an access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use) and use it as username (without password).

Once you have your access token clone the repository:

```
git clone https://<your-access-token>@github.com/username/repo.git
```

Then you can pull without authenticating every single time.

This is the simplest method but will store the token plain text into .git/config To improve security you can [setup password caching](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/caching-your-github-password-in-git) and clone as usual https:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

If you want remove access of server to repository, just delete the access token in your [application settings](https://github.com/settings/applications).

I also prefer to use https than ssh on deploy environments. Some times we don't have enough access privileges to handle with ssh, but https access to github is available even on cheaper hosting services.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. this more robust and can be used for deployment system.

Comment: I think this has to be `git clone https://<your-user-name>:<your-access-token>@github.com/username/repo.git` if your user name is not the same as the repos.

Comment: Works for me with `git clone https://<your-access-token>@github.com/username/repo.git` on private repository as well.

Looks like the user is not required.

Answer (score 14):

**generate ssh key**

```
cd ~/.ssh 
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your-email-address"
touch config
```

**paste in config**

```
 Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/YOUR_KEY
```

**paste public key to github deployment key settings**

```
cat YOUR_KEY.pub
```

**set remote from http to ssh**

```
git remote set-url origin ssh://git@github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Comment: The `set-url origin ssh` was the missing part on my side. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be done by using credential caching and using the .netrc file. 
[Please Check This](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Permanently+authenticating+with+Git+repositories)